# Where should i put in DISTINCT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to only fetch unique result of several duplicates in this little complex query:

```
$sql = "SELECT t1.*, t2.floor_id
        FROM dbo.IMP_ELEMENT AS t1
        INNER JOIN dbo.IMP_MODEL_GEOMETRY t2 ON CONCAT(t1.Project, '_', t1.element_mark) = CONCAT(t2.Project, '_', t2.element_mark)
        WHERE CONCAT(t2.Project, '-', t2.floor_id) LIKE '%$objNr%'";
```

I expect to only receive unique result from t2.element_mark.
So where should I put in DISTINCT? or is there another way to achieve this?

In t1, Element_mark is unique, but in t2, Element_mark can have duplicates.

So from t1 I like to receive all data. But from t2 I want DISTINCT element_mark. From t2 i only display floor_id, But I need to use Element_mark and Project to match t1 & t2 rows.

**EDIT**
It doesn't matter which of the duplicates in t2.element_mark I display. t2.floor_id is the same on all duplicates.

**

```
t1
----------------------------------------------
id    project    element_mark     type     ...
0     1          1                A        ...
1     1          2                A        ...
2     1          3                A        ...

t2
----------------------------------------------
id    project    element_mark    flood_id    ...
0     1          1               1           ...
1     1          1               1           ...
2     1          2               1           ...
3     1          3               2           ...
```

As seen in t1, all element_mark is unique. But in t2, element_mark can be seen twice or more.
What I want is to select * from t1.
The id like to select DISTINCT element_mark, floor_id FROM t2 WHERE CONCAT(t1.project, '*', t1.element_mark) = CONCAT(t2.project, '*', t2.element_mark)

Comment: sample data and expected output is helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like below using subquery

```
SELECT  t1.*, t2.floor_id
        FROM dbo.IMP_ELEMENT AS t1
        INNER JOIN (select distinct project,element_mark,flood_id from dbo.IMP_MODEL_GEOMETRY) t2 ON CONCAT(t1.Project, '_', t1.element_mark) = CONCAT(t2.Project, '_', t2.element_mark)
        WHERE CONCAT(t2.Project, '-', t2.floor_id) LIKE '%$objNr%'
```

Comment: But in t1 i have have a column named "Typ". There can be duplicates and it's ok. Doesn't this affect ALL columns in t1 ? I only want distinct for "element_mark"

Comment: Will project, element_mark and floor_id be distinct? Or just Project? It's only element_mark wich needs to be distinct!

Comment: @BjörnC it will create distinct using  project, element_mark and floor_id

Comment: ok, but i cannot have distinct project or distinct floor_id. But i found the solution: `INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(element_mark), project, floor_id from dbo.IMP_MODEL_GEOMETRY) t2 ON CONCAT(t1.Project, '_', t1.element_mark) = CONCAT(t2.Project, '_', t2.element_mark)`

Comment: Thank you for leading the way!

Answer (score 0):

If as you say

> t2.floor_id is the same on all duplicates.

then your query is fine and you can add DISTINCT in your select

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT t1.*, t2.floor_id
        FROM dbo.IMP_ELEMENT AS t1
        INNER JOIN dbo.IMP_MODEL_GEOMETRY t2 ON CONCAT(t1.Project, '_', t1.element_mark) = CONCAT(t2.Project, '_', t2.element_mark)
        WHERE CONCAT(t2.Project, '-', t2.floor_id) LIKE '%$objNr%'";
```

**UPDATE:**

Your query returns

```
----------------------------------------------
id    project    element_mark     type     flood_id
0     1          1                A        1
0     1          1                A        1
1     1          2                A        1
2     1          3                A        2
```

Adding Distinct returns

```
----------------------------------------------
id    project    element_mark     type     flood_id
0     1          1                A        1
1     1          2                A        1
2     1          3                A        2
```

Comment: I cannot use Distinct on t1.

Comment: Why not? DISTINCT t1.*, t2.floor_id will give you all distinct entries in t1 followed by distinct t2.floor_id

Comment: But will it not get DISTINCT type FROM t1? the only selecting one row? i wan't all rows from t1. Or is it DISCTINCT rows from t1 ? I don't get it!

Comment: By doing distinct t1.* on a table it checks all columns combined. Based on your example data distinct t1.* will return 3 rows.